# Division by zero error in WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently bought a WordPress theme that does a fancy gallery display of photos and it has been getting the following errors on the homepage.

Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/21/4913121/html/stsudios/wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/front-gal.php on line 36

Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/21/4913121/html/stsudios/wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/front-gal.php on line 48

The following is the code through line 50 - the lines with `/**/` are the trouble ones.  Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php

global $postgallery;
$show = $postgallery->get_post_option('show');
$arr = $postgallery->get_post_option('show_'.$show);
$arr = explode(",", $arr);
$arr = (array)$arr;

//$myterms = get_terms('dt_gallery_cat');
$myterms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy'=> 'dt_gallery_cat'));

$images = array();

global $term, $h;

foreach ($myterms as $term)
{

   if ($show == "all")
   {

   }
   elseif ($show == "only")
   {
      if ( !in_array( $term->term_id, $arr ) )
         continue;
   }
   elseif ($show == "except")
   {
      if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $arr ) )
         continue;
   }

   $term->pic = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term->image_id, 'full' );

   $k = $term->pic[1] / $term->pic[2];

   /**/$term->pic = $term->pic[0];/**/

   $size = taxonomy_get_size( $term->term_id );
   if ($size == "s")
      $w = 220;
   if ($size == "m")
      $w = 460;
   if ($size == "l")
      $w = 700;

   /**/$h = ceil($w / $k);/**/

   $term->pic = get_template_directory_uri().'/thumb.php?src='.$term->pic.'&amp;w='.$w.'&amp;h='.$h.'&amp;zc=1';
```

Comment: Ask for a refund. Wordpress themes cost money?!

Comment: Preset `$w` to a "default" expected size since if `$size` isn't set, `$w` isn't being set which is causing part of the problem.

Comment: Themeforest themes are scary: "Set CHMOD 777 to folder “your_site/wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/cache” 2) Folder “your_site/wp-content/uploads” must be created and CHMOD set to 777" Yea, right. Hello, hackers, please hack me.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Themeforest myself, but my husband loves their designs.  They do have some graphically beautiful themes, but definitely lack on instructions, functionality, and security.

Answer (score 2):

If you add in some code to check that the values aren't zero it should stop it doing this, but there may be bigger problems.

```
if ( $term->pic[1] == 0 || $term->pic[2] == 0 ) return
```

and / or

```
$h = ( $w > 0 && $k > 0 ) ? ceil($w / $k) : 0;
```

These values probably shouldn't be zero though, so there is likely something else going wrong. Perhaps your images are not in a format readable by the code... or you haven't uploaded any yet

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I thought the same thing, but after adding in the images, the site works, but still displays the error messages first while the images are loading.  Will try this addition.